# How to Set the Default working directory in python 3 IDLE in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I try to open any python script the default path it shows is '/home/username' and my files are located at '/home/username/Documents/python' which i want to be the default directory when i want to save or open some files. I have already tried os.chdir() but it didn't worked. [I have seen this but didn't worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810743/how-to-set-the-current-working-directory-in-python).Thanks in advance

Comment: Save or open files from where? Python is a programming language, not an editor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default save path for Python IDLE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424398/default-save-path-for-python-idle)